# static library with core data (Cannot archive)

Tags: ios, core-data, bundle, static-libraries, archive

After making a static library to handle the core data related code for my app, and making the bundle needed to be able to have the static library access the (core data) database.
I finally have everything working when testing on my device.

Unfortunately when I want to Product/Archive the app (to make an IPA file) it does not work.
Here is what I get in the debugger:

> CpResource
>   /Users/neptune/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Factorial-ekduhgrmnbgyteaokxccduhudcno/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Factorial/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/CoreDataResource.bundle
>   /Users/neptune/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Factorial-ekduhgrmnbgyteaokxccduhudcno/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Factorial/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Factorial.app/CoreDataResource.bundle
>
> cd /Users/neptune/Documents/Factorial
>
> setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>
> builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -strip-debug-symbols -strip-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip
>   -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/neptune/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Factorial-ekduhgrmnbgyteaokxccduhudcno/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Factorial/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/CoreDataResource.bundle
>   /Users/neptune/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Factorial-ekduhgrmnbgyteaokxccduhudcno/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Factorial/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Factorial.app
>
> error:
>   /Users/neptune/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Factorial-ekduhgrmnbgyteaokxccduhudcno/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Factorial/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/CoreDataResource.bundle:
>   No such file or directory

I have tried everything I could think about, but up to this point with no success. This is my first time to use a bundle inside my app, so I might well be missing some basic point.
Any relevant tip, by anyone with similar or more  experience, will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the bundle to the target? Maybe you only added it to a dev target but not the production one.

Comment: Yes I added it to the target, because it works on the device. But how could I add it to the dev target and not to the production one. As far as I am aware of I have only one target. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: I was speculating that you have more than one target. Did you try a complete clean (shift-alt-K) and restarting Xcode?

Comment: I have only one target for this app, debug and production. I have other targets in the project, but for different apps. Yes I did a complete clean many times. I suppose I have some settings wrong but don't know what.

Comment: I updated my post with more information, hoping it will shed some light.